# C# Asp.net mvc как отобразить на view объект DataTable в виде таблицы, которая обладает возможностью редактирования полей и добавления новых строк

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, datatable

C# Asp.net mvc как отобразить на view объект DataTable в виде таблицы, которая обладает возможностью редактирования полей и добавления новых строк

Comment: все эти возможности добавляются к обычной html таблице c помощью js. Либо используйте готовую компоненту на js. Например - jqgrid

Comment: @teovankot а если я не знаю структуры таблицы, тоесть может прийти таблица любой структуры, но она должна отобразиться и иметь возможность добавлять/изменять/удалять элементы

Comment: У некоторых компонент можно определять настройки. Но это обычно лишние не нужные сложности.

Answer (score 1):

Для вывода таблиц с некоторыми дополнительными возможностями можно взять [JqGrid](http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/17.3.php)
Но как правило, можно обойтись и обычными элементами html, просто определив элемент table, кнопки/ссылки для удаления, добавления, редактирования и задав код javascript, который делал бы все в Ajax-режиме

Comment: да, можно просто с table и кнопками, но это делается если ты знаешь структуру таблицы, какие там столбцы, сколько их и какие типы, а мне нужно чтобы все это делалось независимо от структуры datatable

Comment: а нельзя ли для одного типа данных сделать одно преставление, для другого другое, чтобы знать точно какая структура и в соответствии с этим создавать столбцы в таблице?

Comment: то можно, но хочется какуюнить универсальную штуку, если не найду ничего- придется так и делать